# Activity open in another bottom window in split window mode android

Tags: android, multi-window

I have one application with two activity(A, B Activity B start from activity A) and my application is supporting multiwindow mode but the problem is when the app is starting in multi-window mode Activity A is display in one window and another application is display in another second window. As soon as we start Activity B from Activity A, Activity B open in another window(Second Window) instead of First Window.

Other Information
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 28
android:resizeableActivity=true in Menifest file for activity

Any suggestion is welcome to solve this issue.